# Find the points on the curve y=(sinx)/(2+cosx) at which the tangent is horizontal. Supplemental question about a different scenario.

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

> Find the points on the curve $ y = \frac { \sin x }{ 2 + \cos x} $ at which the tangent is horizontal.

I'd like some input on whether I solved this correctly or not as trig has never been a particularly strong point for me. I found a similar question and moved forward based off reading through [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165443/finding-horizontal-tangents-for-trig-function).

$$y'=\frac{2\cos x + 1}{(2+\cos x)^2}$$

I'm not exactly sure why, but from the previously linked thread, it looks like I shouldn't be concerned about the $ (2 + \cos x)^2 $ because it cannot equal zero, so I can just put $ 2 \cos x = 0$ and solve so $ x = \frac{2\pi}{3} , x = \frac{5\pi}{3}$ then plugging it back into the original equation I end up with $ y (\frac{2\pi}{3}) = \frac{\sqrt3}{3}$ and $ y (\frac{5\pi}{3}) = -\frac{\sqrt3}{3}$

Therefore, there exist horizontal tangents at $ ( \frac{2\pi}{3} + 2\pi n , \frac{\sqrt3}{3} ),( \frac{5\pi}{3} + 2\pi n , -\frac{\sqrt3}{3} ), n\in\mathbb{Z}$

As some supplemental inquiries, how would the results be altered if the equation were this?$$ \frac{ \sin x }{ 1 + \cos x} $$ There would be a vertical aymptote when $ x = \pi $ right? Would that affect the horizontal tangent at all? And could I get an explanation as to why I don't need to put the whole equation equal to zero?

Edit: Altered answer to include for infinite values where the derivative is equal to zero and correct an error

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "put $2\cos(x) = 0$" here. Definitely, because $-1 \le \cos(x) \le 1$, you'll always have $(2+ \cos(x))^2 > 0$, but that means we want to find where the numerator is zero in order to find where the derivative is zero as a whole. So to do that we want to find the $x$ so that $2\cos(x) + 1= 0$, or $2\cos(x) = -1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not exactly sure why, but from the previously linked thread, it looks like I shouldn't be concerned about the $(2+\cos x)^2$ because it cannot equal zero

This is because a fraction can only be zero when the numerator is zero ($\frac{1}{n}$ is never zero no matter what $n$ is, similarly $\frac{x}{n}$ is only zero when $x$ is zero). However, you do need to check if the fraction is defined (the denominator is not zero). In this case it will never be zero, because $\cos x \neq -2$.

Now the numerator is zero when 
$$2\cos x + 1 = 0 \,\, \Rightarrow x=\frac{2}{3}(3\pi n-\pi), n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
The derivative has an infinite number of zeros, meaning there's an infinite number of points of horizontal tangency.

In this case $y(x)$ is bounded and $y(\frac{2}{3}(3\pi n-\pi)) = \pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}, n\in\mathbb{Z}$ so all lines of horizontal tangency lie on the lines $y=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

> how would the results be altered if the equation were $\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}$ ?

Your intuition is correct, there will a vertical asymptote at $x=\pi$ and in fact at $x=\pi (2n+1), n\in\mathbb{Z}$. However, $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}) = \frac{1}{1+ \cos x}$, which like $\frac{1}{n}$ can never be zero.

Comment: So does that mean that any time when I have a denominator that cannot equal zero, I should only be concerned with finding a value of the numerator to make $ f'(x) = 0 $ when finding horizontal tangents?

Comment: @Vin Yes, that should be. Once we have $\frac{a}{b}=0$ where $b\neq 0$, then $a=0$.